# Form of quadratic with no real roots.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help showing that quadratic functions with real coefficients that do not have any
real zeros are of the form $a(z−w)(z−w ̄)$,where $w\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

The only section in my book proceeding this question is the proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra which states: every non-constant polynomials with complex coefficients has at least one root in the complex numbers. Is there a way I can appeal to this?

Comment: What happens if you multiply out that expression you have?

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Lastly, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Show"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: What have you tried here?  Do you know how the discriminant of a quadratic polynomial (the quantity under the radical in the quadratic formula) *discriminates* between those equations with real solutions and those without real solutions.

Comment: Again: expand out $a(z-w)(z-\bar{w})$ as a polynomial in $z$. What do you notice?

Comment: After expanding I still have the $az^2$ term, is there a way to show that is not a real zero? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quadratic has the form $q(z) = a_0+ a_1 z + a_2 z^2$, with $a_2 \neq 0$, and you are 
given that $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$.

The fundamental theorem of Algebra let us write this in the form $q(z) = a_2 (z-w_1)(z-w_2)$.

If $w_1$ or $w_2$ were real, then $q$ would have a real root. So $w_1,w_2$ have non-zero imaginary parts.

Since $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $q(x) = \overline{q(x)}$. Expanding both sides gives two equal quadratics in $x$, hence the coefficients are equal. Equating the coefficients gives two equations involving $w_1,w_2$. Use these two equations to figure out a relationship between $\Im w_1$ and $\Im w_2$, and then the relationship between $\Re w_1$ and $\Re w_2$.